# Spring Boot beans not added to context using Bazel

Tags: java, spring-boot, bazel, applicationcontext, spring-bean

I have one Spring Boot application that uses Bazel to manage all of its dependencies, that I migrated from Maven.

I'm able to launch the app using Bazel, but after checking all of its beans I noticed that are missing the beans of the classes that I created using the `@Component, @Service and @Repository` annotations.

If I use Maven, these beans are added to the Application context as expected.

Is something missing in my Bazel configuration? How can I generate and add these beans to my application context?

Comment: Could you solve this issue?